# In thermodynamics, does an open system have some kind of wall with which they can identify?

Tags: thermodynamics

Does an open system, like a glass with water inside exposed to the atmosphere, have walls? Can an open system be said to have walls?, if we can say that an open system has walls, can its walls be classified as rigid or mobile or with another type of classification? Or, in this type of system (open system), does the concept of a wall not apply?

Comment: What does the presence or absence of a lid have to do with the rigidity of the walls of the container?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: An open system is one for which mass can flow in or out.  A closed system has constant mass.

Answer (score 1):

Syringe is usually modeled as cylinder with a piston - it is only one wall that moves, and there is usually a force applied to it, or a work done by they gas/liquid pushing against this wall, since the wall has some mass and because there is a friction force that prevents moving it.

In case of a gas/liquid in a glass we have a system that is open. The conditions are different from those that exist in a syringe, and there are appropriate ways of modeling such systems. Notably, we would often work in an [isobaric ensemble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isothermal%E2%80%93isobaric_ensemble), since we have pressure fixed to be the air pressure. (Although problems like expansion of a gas into vacuum are also considered.)

Note also that many of these problems involve non-equilibrium conditions - like hot coffee in a cup, in contact with much cooler air. Also, in case of a liquid we deal with a phase transformation - the liquid remains in the glass because of gravity, but even in the conditions without gravity (and without glass/cup) it would keep compact form rather than spread everywhere, as a gas does.

Answer (score 1):

Wall is defined by the enclosing of a certain area we are concerned with , Wall can be present in any object we are concerned with like a cup , a piston. Anything which you are concerned with which your ending covers it is a wall. The movability does very little to strip the title of wall from wall.

When Matter and energy are exchanged with atmosphere (as a cup of coffee open in air) it is said to be a open system and it has a partial diathermal wall(because all of it is not covered in wall and hence allows particles to escape). Then we have the diathermal wall which allows energy transfer between systems but not matter(a closed box of hot water radiates heat but no water escapes) . Finally the adiabatic wall which does not allow both energy and matter transfer (thermoflask).

The movability of the system/wall has very little to do with these classifications of wall. Movability refers to (as the name suggests) the freedom to move a wall in the system , like opening one end of the wall in a box to put some electrical stirrer in the box with water is an example of a movable wall. Syringe has a movable wall for the air inside it because one end is **moving**.
Rigid wall refers to probably an unmovable wall

Answer (score 1):

"Rigid walls" is usually a natural-language way to say "fixed volume" - meaning that regardless of what happens to the system, its total volume is not permitted to change.  If you want to know whether a coffee mug exposed to air constitutes a rigid container for the liquid inside, ask if it's possible for the liquid to expand or contract.